# Remove seconds from the timestamp field in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am new to PowerBI and hence this question might be very simple but it would be very helpful if you help me with it.
I have a field in my table "A_Timestamp" and the value is

01/02/18 12:08:25

I want to ignore the seconds and display the result as

01/02/18 12:08

How can this be achieved?

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards,
Ani

Comment: You can change the "Format" in the modelling tab of the toolbar. Would that be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the Query Editor and add a Custom Column, with a calculation something like the following:

```
= DateTime.From ( DateTime.ToText( [A_Timestamp] , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") )
```

You can then add steps to remove the original **A_Timestamp** column, rename the added column, and reset the datatype to Date/Time.

Comment: If it helps other readers, you can use `HH:mm` to return 24-hour time. This ensures that you don't accidentally change 1 PM to 1 AM, for example.